# index, first and last meta links and rel attributes

Tags: html, rel

Are the "index", "first" and "last" meta links and rel attributes deprecated?

I'm developing a cms that uses them for pagination in the head's meta links and rel attributes within the pagination nav.

But when I wanted to validate the page as html5 I got them as a bad value.

Where are they gone? only "prev" and "next" pass the validation.

Even in the whatwg list they don't exist http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes

Should I remove them?

Thanks.

Comment: Intresting... never heard of those meta.

Comment: @Jose: these are used to tell search engines for example that the current document is a part of a series (pagination)

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 adopted this [Change Proposal](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2010Nov/0042.html) as documented [here](http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=7475#c15)

Frankly, the arguments are dubious. There are plug-ins for browsers, one of which I use, which make use of rel="first" and rel="last".

The rel registry is now officially run by the [Microformats.com](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values) site. Hopefully, the "index", "first" and "last" rel types will be readopted there in due course.

UPDATE: Note that there is a ongoing discussion about this on the W3C HTML5 WG mailing list. The thread starts at http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011Jun/0314.html